# How to disable back press when Swipe to layout is Refreshing layout in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

Im getting problem with swipe to refresh layout, if swipe for refresh my layout on that time if I pressed back button it close all activity's and fragments..
i checked log but there no Application Terminated error...

Comment: Are you performing any action `onBackPressed()` or `onKeyDown()` method?

Comment: @Piyush No method/Action used in onBackpressed() in fact i didn't use onBackpressed() method

Comment: @DhanveshKumkar did u solved it?

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes ...Thank You

Comment: @NileshRathod Sure Sir :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`isRefreshing()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#isRefreshing())

> Whether the `SwipeRefreshWidget` is actively showing refresh progress.

Sample code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
           //  swipeRefreshLayout is Refreshing
        }else {
           //  swipeRefreshLayout is not Refreshing call super.onBackPressed();
           super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do we use this code? if on MainActivity how to get handle for swipeRefreshLayout?